# Convert true/false in gridmvc to yes/no

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5

Im dislpaying my verify field in using gridmvc and since its a bool it returns yes/no for true/false. As the question states, I'm trying to convert the true false to yes/no but im getting an error in the code below `bool cannot be converted to string`  I'm not exactly sure why this isnt working since im comparing the value to true and if its true yes...or no.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Regards

```
   if (colums.Add().RenderValueAs(data => data.verify== true) ?
     //if (colums.Add(data => data.verify== true) ?
        colums.Add().RenderValueAs(model => "Yes") :
        colums.Add().RenderValueAs(model => "No"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
 colums.Add().RenderValueAs(data => data.verify ? "yes" : "no")
```

But a better solution would be to handle such logic in the ViewModel.

Comment: That's strange. Can you post more of the code. Is the type of the property `verify` bool?

Comment: You cannot filter or sort when using this method. For that you would need to generate the property in the controller.